# Does parse sdk provide API to retrieve push notification history .?

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I check the parse.com SDK document and didn't find any API to retrieve push notification list/history.

Is there any way to get this information?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTiN8.png)

Answer (score 0):

This cannot currently be done via the Parse.com API

https://www.parse.com/questions/can-i-getdelete-push-notifications-history-via-rest-api

Note: Though this answer is from two years ago, it doesnt seem like it is anywhere besides the Parse dashboard.